# iOS: detecting touch on image within UIImageView containing multiple images

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, touch, collision-detection

I got an UIImageView composed of two images with transparancy channel activated.

The view looks something like this:
[image](http://www.tomatosoft.biz/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/metal-button.png)

I would like to be able to detect precisely the touches within the center circle and distinguish them from the ones in the outern circle.

I am thinking of a collision detection algorithm based the difference between two circles. First test in the outern layer to see if there is a collision at all and then in the inner layer. If in the inner layer then activate inner botton otherwise active outern button.

Any help or suggestion in this?

Shall I create a github repo so everyone could contribute in it?

Comment: Is the radius of the two circles known in advance

Comment: Just half the image width I'd assume?

Comment: yes exactly, can be known by dividing the width.. however the radius of the inner circle is smaller than the outern circle one.. so is best to use the inner one.

Answer (score 1):

Here something than can help you:

```
    UIImageView *myImageView;
 // In viewDidLoad, the place you are created your UIImageView place this:

myImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapInView = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapInImageView:)];
[myImageView addGestureRecognizer:tapInView];

}

-(void)tapInImageView:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tap
{
CGPoint tapPoint = [tap locationInView:tap.view];

CGPoint centerView = tap.view.center;

double distanceToCenter = sqrt((tapPoint.x - centerView.x)*(tapPoint.x - centerView.x) + (tapPoint.y - centerView.y)*(tapPoint.y - centerView.y) );
if (distanceToCenter < RADIUS) {
    // It's in center
} else {
    // Touch outside
}
```

Comment: Just a side note - not really related to the problem: 
I don't think in this case it is a performance issue. But just in case or if you want to re-use this within some larger loop ... don't take the square route for `distanceToCenter` but compare it with the square of the `RADIUS`. That is much faster, especially when RADIUS is a constant anyway. But even if it is variable `a * a` computes much faster than `sqrt(b)` while `b < a*a` and `sqrt(b) < a' are equivalent for all positive values of a and b.

Comment: Ok, I take note. Thank you.